# Can't style element in shadow dom in media query

Tags: css, polymer, polymer-1.0

In my `styles/app-theme.html` I am trying to change the menu icon size of `paper-drawer-panel` in the media query. This element is in index.html. Since it is in the shadow dom, I can't seem to access it. I tried with:

Probably not relevant, but here is the index.html:

```
  <template is="dom-bind" id="app">
    <paper-drawer-panel force-narrow="true">
      <div drawer>
        <drawer-custom></drawer-custom>
      </div>
      <div main>
        <div id="header-v-center">
          <paper-icon-button id="paper-toggle" icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle>
```

---

```
  @media (max-width: 600px) {
    iron-icon#icon::shadow {
      height: 6px;
      width: 5px;
    }
  }
```

---

and

```
  @media (max-width: 600px) {

    :root {
      --iron-icon-height: 6px;
      --iron-icon-width: 50px;
    }
  }
```

To no success. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Polymer currently uses a shim (a partial polyfill) to evaluate custom properties.  As such, they aren't automatically recalculated.  What you can do, however, is use [iron-media-query](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-media-query) (or directly use [matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Testing_media_queries)) to know when to call [updateStyles](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/api/#Polymer.Base:method-updateStyles) on the element(s) that need updating.

[Here's an example of using updateStyles](http://jsbin.com/duyitajoxe/edit?html,output):

```js
Polymer({

    is: 'seed-element',

    properties: {
      largeScreen: {
        type: Boolean,
        observer: '_largeScreenChanged'
      }
    },
    
    _largeScreenChanged: function(newValue) {
      this.updateStyles({
        '--h1-color': (newValue ? 'red' : 'blue')
      });
    }
  });
```

```html
<dom-module id="seed-element">
  <template>
    <style>
      h1 {
        color: var(--h1-color, red);
      }
    </style>
    
    <h1>header</h1>
    
    <iron-media-query query="(max-width: 600px)" query-matches="{{largeScreen}}"></iron-media-query>
  </template>

</dom-module>

<seed-element id="topmenu"></seed-element>
```

Comment: Ok, I thought this was for only custom elements rather than styling the polymer components. I got this impression since the polymer starter kit app-theme had preset `@media` queries.