# How to set :host {} based on media query in Polymer?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have to set height on the `:root` element, or else I will not get the viewport size that I want with a scrollbar. However, I only want to set `height: calc(100% - 130px);` when the viewport is less than 900px.

How can I do this since I can not use `@media` query? I tried this to no success:

```
<template>
    <style include="iron-flex iron-flex-alignment">
     :host[show] {
       background-color: var(--pink-color);
       width: 100%;
       overflow-x: hidden;
       overflow-y: auto;
       outline: none;
       display: flex;
     }

     :host[smallScreen] {
       height: calc(100% - 130px);
     }

    <div hidden$="{{!show}}">
      <iron-media-query query="(max-width: 899px)"
         query-matches="{{smallScreen}}"></iron-media-query>
...
 <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'video-selection',
      properties: {
        show: {
          type: Boolean,
          value: true,
          reflectToAttribute: true
        },
        smallScreen: {
          type: Boolean,
          value: false,
          reflectToAttribute: true
        }
      },
```

Comment: Follow up to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36783006/cant-style-element-in-shadow-dom-in-media-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need

```
 :host([small-screen]) {
   height: calc(100% - 130px);
 }
```

[**JSBin example**](http://jsbin.com/zutayacewa/1/edit?html,output)

Comment: naw...still not being applied. I also tried `:host([smallScreen])`

Comment: Did you check in devtools the `smallScreen` attribute was actually added?

Comment: The `small-screen` attribute is added on the html element. But in dev tools styles I only see `.video-selection-0[show]` with no `height`. There is no `.video-selection-0[smallScreen] `

Comment: That was it! What a crazy gotcha. Usually, everything outside of html is snakeCase and automatically converted in the html. Thanks, I never would of thought that.